# Value is null when passing from controller to view in Yii

Tags: yii2

Why can't I pass a value from the controller to a view? The value is not null, but it seems that the value is not passed to the view page. Why?

Below is my code:

#### Controller (SiteController.php):

```
public function actionProfileuser()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;

    if($session['UserID'] == null){
        Yii::$app->user->logout();
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    else
    {
        //$model = User::find()->where(['ID'=>$session['UserID']])->all();
        //$model = new User;
        $model = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->from('tbl_user')
            ->where(['ID' => $session['UserID']])
            ->all();
        return $this->render('profileuser', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### View (profileuser.php):

```
<?= $model->Name; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you retrieve a collections of
models, `all()`. If you need just one, use one():

```
public function actionProfileuser()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;

    if($session['UserID'] == null){
        Yii::$app->user->logout();
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    else
    {
        //$model = User::find()->where(['ID'=>$session['UserID']])->all();
        //$model = new User;
        $model = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->from('tbl_user')
            ->where(['ID' => $session['UserID']])
            ->one(); // <---------- use one()
        return $this->render('profileuser', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### View (profileuser.php):

```
<?= $model['Name']; ?>
```

Or using all, you should iterate over the modes. Fr showing all the results:

```
foreach( $model AS $key => $value){

    echo $value->name;
}
```

Comment: it works when i use one() but i change $model->Name to $model['Name']; in View. Idk why the arrow sign doesnt work.

Comment: because  the one return an array  ..  and not an object   https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#one()-detail  answer  updated ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use code similar to what is generated by Gii:

```
$model = User::findOne($session['UserID']);
if ($model === null) {
    throw new ForbiddenHttpException('You are not authorized to view this page.');
}
```

It will fetch the `User` model from the database and throw an exception if the requested user does not exist.

`one()` or `findOne()` does not guarantee that it will return non-null, so you need to check it yourself.

`\yii\db\Query()` is for raw queries. It will not return you a model. In the best case you will get a query result as an array.